# Get span text using jquery

Tags: jquery, pagination

How do I get the active page number of my pagination?

```
<div class="pages">
<ul>
  <li class="prev">
       <a href="#"><span>previous</span></a>
   </li>
  <li class="pagination-page-numbers">
       <a href="#"><span>1</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="pagination-page-numbers">
       <a href="#"><span>2</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="pagination-page-numbers on">
       <a href="#"><span>3</span></a>
  </li>
  <li class="next">
  <span><span>next</span></span>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.pagination-page-numbers.on').find('span').text();
```

Comment: @fini- Thank you so much :)